# ColdFusion file upload issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I've got the CFFileUpload working on my local dev system, I just uploaded it to my production server - both are running ColdFusion 9.  Everything works fine on my local dev box.

When I try to access the page with the uploader, from the production box I get

```
};ColdFusion.Event.registerOnLoad(_cf_fileupload_init_1366123463704);
```

The differences:
dev = Windows 7
prod = Windows Server 2003
that's about it.

Any ideas??

Comment: Is the ColdFusion service on your production box running as an account that has access to the destination directory?

Comment: behavior is the same if I run the service at local system or administrator

Comment: You may have different cumulative hotfixes, or security patches applied - does the contents of your lib/updates folders match or are they different?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on some forum, the CFID reference to the scripts used by the UI components needs to be "browsable" - making a mapping in Apache fixed the problem. - I had locked down my Prod box, and forgot the mappings were not the same on each virtual host.